# General application log

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

In my Node.js applications, I often find it helpful to have an application log so that should something go wrong in production, I can have more information than I get from a crash stack trace to track down problems.

To facilitate this, I use a global instance of [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) which is set up as one of the first things in my code:

```
var winston = require('winston');

global.applog = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      timestamp: true,
      level: 'debug'
    })
  ]
});
```

I then call `applog.debug()`, `applog.info()`, `applog.warn()`, and `applog.error()` as appropriate throughout my code.  Even if I am in a class included from the main application, I will often send debug messages.

For *my* purposes, this works great.  I get the information I need to keep things running smoothly, and handle unexpected behaviors.  However:

- This reduces the reuse of any lib code as it cannot stand on its own without having a reference to `applog`.
- It doesn't feel like a best practice to have global references used inside modular object-oriented code.
- I don't think I would ever use a log utility that didn't have the standard methods (`debug`, `info`, `warn`, `error`), but if I did switch away from Winston it's possible that all my code would need to be updated.

Is there a more appropriate pattern I should be following for logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a log for a production application is an excellent idea. Some quick notes on logging web applications in general:

> Application logging should be always be included for security events.
>
> ...
>
> Each log entry needs to include sufficient information for the
>   intended subsequent monitoring and analysis. It could be full content
>   data, but is more likely to be an extract or just summary properties.
>   The application logs must record "when, where, who and what" for each
>   event.

- [OWASP Loggin Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Logging_Cheat_Sheet)

With that in mind, winston is generally considered a good choice for Node.js logging. It's dependencies are a little dated, and support is minimal. Another option is [Scribe.js](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/Scribe.js) (lightweight, but also minimal support).

---

> This reduces the reuse of any lib code as it cannot stand on its own
>   without having a reference to `applog`.

Not necessarily something bad. What you have is compact and easy to transport. You could consider pulling this snippet into it's own file and then `require`-ing that file in each JS script as needed.

I'm not aware of anything you can do to overcome this.

> It doesn't feel like a best practice to have global references used
>   inside modular object-oriented code.

You're right, global variables/functions in general aren't the best. They can cause issues with naming and referencing in the global scope. There are a few solutions to this, [w3 has a section devote to avoiding globals](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals).

If your snippet can be placed inside a class (ES6 only) or an app object, I suggest that.

> if I did switch away from Winston it's possible that all my code would
>   need to be updated.

Certainly something to think about. With a "find and replace all" command (using a regex perhaps in your IDE) though, much of the hassle could easily be taken care of.